# Getting XMLHttpRequest error while fetching data from website in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I got this "XMLHttpRequest" error and I've been trying to fix it for hours without any results. Here is my code:

```
var response = await http.get(Uri.https('sigarra.up.pt','feup/pt/cantina.ementashow#7'));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(jsonData);
```

I have more code, but at the moment I'm just trying to see if it gets the information from the website, which apparently doesn't do it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This means that the server isn't adding the relevant CORS headers to allow you to access it in a Flutter web application. If you control the server, add the headers; if not, you won't be able to use it in a web app (unless your web app is hosted by the same server).

Comment: Its CORS issue. you need to ask website to handle those. or you can run this web app on particular port by specifying port no. like flutter run -d chrome  --web-port=8000.

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var raw = await HttpReqService.get<String>(
    'https://sigarra.up.pt/feup/pt/cantina.ementashow#7',
    jsonResponse: false,
  );
  print(raw?.substring(0,200));
}
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">
<head>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-1
```